# SharePoint List Does Not Render in XML, but a View of it Does

Tags: xml, sharepoint

I'm trying to render the XML of a SharePoint list.  It works when I reference a specific view, like this:

http://my.site.com/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={}&View={}&XMLDATA=1

But when I remove the &View= component, like this:

http://my.site.com/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={}&XMLDATA=1

I get a "this page cannot be displayed error."  Also, when I create a copy of that view that works, I receive the same error when I try to render the copied version.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use the rest endpoint - the default return format is in xml:

https://my.site.com/subsite/**_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listname')**

(note: subsite is optional) - use it if your list lives at a subsite.

Also, use IE for nicely formatted xml.  To enable it, turn off the feed reading view and restart IE.  Go to **Internet Options -> Content->Feeds and Web Slices->Settings-> uncheck "Turn on feed reading view".**

refer to image below:

[image]

Reference answer here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/164502/7288

Official Microsoft Documentation for list in Rest here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest